# Django - Introspect django Model in a method implemented in its abstract ancestor?

Tags: django, inheritance, abstract-class

In django, I would like to reference the class whose method is being called, where the method itself is implemented in its [abstract ancestor](http://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/db/models/#abstract-base-classes).

```
class AbstractFather(models.Model):
    class Meta:
        abstract = True
    def my_method(self):
        # >>> Here <<<

class Child(AbstractFather):
    pass
```

I'm looking to do something like:

```
isinstance(instance, Child):
```

Of course I can't know within my_method which child Model was called a priori.

Comment: could you clarify? are you saying that self.childmethod() doesn't work? and what is the reason you are structuring it in such a way?

Comment: self within my_method is actually the child's instance, as AbstractFather is... abstract :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Trivial and works:

```
class AbstractFather(models.Model):
    class Meta:
        abstract = True
    def my_method(self,some_instance):
        print isinstance(some_instance,self.__class__)

class Child(AbstractFather):
    pass
```

Answer (score 0):

Why do you say that? You absolutely can. AbstractFather is an abstract model, so it will never be instantiated, so you can always be sure that whatever's calling `my_method` is an instance of a subclass. The syntax you give should work.

*Edit* So what exactly are you trying to compare against? `self` in `my_method` will always be the relevant instance, and its class will always be the specific subclass of AbstractFather. What do you need to check?

Comment: What I meant is that I shouldn't hard-code Child within AbstractFather as there are actually Child1, Child2, etc...  in that sense a priori AbstractFather isn't aware of its children.